# How to hide Startup icon in installshield

Tags: installation

I create a shortcut on startup folder through installshield. i want to load that exe on startup , but i don't want to show that shortcut in program file--> startup folder, How can i do that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create a shortcut, use the registry [Run keys](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314866) to start your application instead. e.g.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`